# problemas al obtener datos de un formulario en javascript

Tags: javascript

Cuando imprimo por `alert` la variable `valor` me aparece `undefined`.

Probé con `document.write` y me sale una página en blanco, me gustaría saber si alguien le ha ocurrido este problema que me pueda ayudar.

```
var valor = document.getElementById('nombre').value;
alert(valor.value);
```

HTML

```
<div class="col-md-6">
  <label>Tu nombre:</label>
  <input type="text" name="nombre" id="nombre" class="form-control" onkeypress="return soloLetras(event)">
</div>
```

Comment: Podés agregar el HTML del formulario?

Comment: Además de que estás intentando llamar a la propiedad `.value` dos veces, ¿en donde se ejecuta ese código? ¿Dónde está ese fragmento de código JavaScript?

Comment: `value` retorna un String y este valor retornado no posee una propiedad `value` , es por eso el `undefined` al intentar acceder en el _alert_

Comment: si es correcta tu respuesta, muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

No debes de utilizar `alert(valor.value);`, sólo `alert(valor);` ya que antes obtuviste el `value`.

Mira:

```js
var valor = document.getElementById('nombre').value;
alert(valor);
```

```html
<form>
  <input id="nombre" value="el dato" />
</form>
```

Comment: coloca el ejemplor para que lo vea

Comment: no uses alert(valor.value);

-- debe ser asi alert(valor); -- solamente

mira https://jsfiddle.net/fmz2e7cu/